# Groovy get today's date at minute 00:00:00

Tags: date, groovy

I have this problem. I need to do the following:

- get todays date
- make a new date which will be today's date at 00:00:00
- make another date which will be today's date at 23:59:59

For example. Today Date is 12-January-2012 19:00

How can i make a new date, which will be 12-January-2012 00:00 (the start of the current day)

It may seems easy, but i couldnt find any groovyway to get it, any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To get the date at midnight use [`Date.clearTime` (docs)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#clearTime()):

```
dateAtMidnight = new Date()
dateAtMidnight.clearTime()
```

*(Javadocs are for Groovy JDK < 2.0, `clearTime()` is declared `void` in Groovy JDK 2.0, preventing `d = new Date().clearTime()`. Comments indicate the original functionality may be restored, yay!)*

For the comparison, instead of using `<= 23:59:59`, use `< (the next day)`:

```
(aDate >= dateAtMidnight) && (aDate < (dateAtMidnight + 1))
```

Comment: `Date.clearTime()` is a Groovy JDK method, so it's the version of Groovy rather than Grails that matters. In Groovy 1.8.2 it returns a `Date`

Comment: @Don Right, and in 2.0 it's void. Not sure how grails got into the discussion.

Comment: @DaveNewton It's going back to Date I think, had a chat with they guy who did the refactoring for Groovy 2 `DateDefaultMethods` and it looks like an oversight that it returns `void`

Comment: @Tim_yates Hope so, I don't like it like this, was going to file a ticket/request to restore original return.

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry, I thought 2.0 was a reference to the Grails version, rather than Groovy (because Groovy 2.0 is not released yet, whereas Grails 2.0 is)

Comment: @DaveNewton It's getting revisited this weekend I believe :-)

Comment: @tim_yates Yay! I haven't gone over the API differences much yet--when this one popped up I realized that was probably a mistake. Although I guess I don't have enough Groovy code in production to be *super* worried, I do use some Groovy projects (easyb in particular) that might be affected more than I thought they might be.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way, but it sets the datetime (but it doesn't get the date merely)

`dateAtMidnight = new Date()
dateAtMidnight.set(hourOfDay: 0, minute: 0, second: 0)`